# Do I need a dialplan?

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-java

I'm getting started with Asterisk and I have to develop an app that will only be used to call people (an alarm system).

I'm using Java and Asterisk-Java, and I read that on their GitHub:

> Did you know you can originate directly into AGI? This is really powerful and eliminates the need for dialplan when doing AGI.

So, if I get it properly, that means I can do without a dialplan.

Though, I can't get Asterisk-Java to work properly, but I don't know it is because I have no dial plan or for some other reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need dialplan for anything except outgoing calling(initiated from asterisk side).

If you using only Originate and not need hangup handlers, caller id etc etc you can go without dialplan.

But in most cases it will be really tricky and usless.

Comment: The only things I need is calling from my app, record a DMTF code and stream a file. Though I'd like to do things properly : where can I learn how to write a Dialplan?

Comment: And what should I put in it? I mean I don't know to what extent things should be done in the Dialplan or rather from Java

Comment: You need start not from dialplan. Read basic book. For example ORelly's Asterisk The future of telephony